# Apache tomcat printing random nullpointers

Tags: apache, tomcat, nullpointerexception, catalina

Our apache tomcat server is printing random nullpointer exceptions. Normally you would see a stacktrace..

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | srvmain | 2012/03/30 13:44:43.733 | SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet frontend threw exception 
INFO   | jvm 1    | srvmain | 2012/03/30 13:44:43.733 | java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO   | jvm 1    | srvmain | 2012/03/30 13:44:46.139 | Mar 30, 2012 1:44:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO   | jvm 1    | srvmain | 2012/03/30 13:44:46.139 | SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet frontend threw exception
INFO   | jvm 1    | srvmain | 2012/03/30 13:44:46.139 | java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO   | jvm 1    | srvmain | 2012/03/30 13:44:47.998 | Mar 30, 2012 1:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO   | jvm 1    | srvmain | 2012/03/30 13:44:47.998 | SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet frontend threw exception
INFO   | jvm 1    | srvmain | 2012/03/30 13:44:47.998 | java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO   | jvm 1    | srvmain | 2012/03/30 13:44:50.623 | Mar 30, 2012 1:44:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
```

Comment: Can you please increase log level to debug and re-post detailed log?

Comment: I can't. Not allowed to restart server.

Comment: This is very generic error, so until you provide more info, I'm not able to help

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to restart the server if you want complete stack traces. You need to set the following JVM option:
XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow